# Storing vechicle for friend

Tags: property

I stored a truck for a friend who died. Do I have to give it to his estate? His daughter said she didn't care. I have had possession for 3 months. What do I do.

Comment: You can never own something on the onus of storing it for someone. You had possession under the explicit assumption that it was only in storage and would be returned to its owner upon request. If you know they died, you would need to make an effort to contact either their estate or their family to notify them of their belongings in your possession. As pointed out in the answer, you also cannot legally do *anything* with a car without having the title for it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to own the truck, you would need to get the title transferred to you. The details depend on what state you are in, but generally they require the owner to sign the back of the title where it indicates title transfer, then you file that with the state DMV (and pay fees). There is often a cost assigned to new owners that can be reduced if the vehicle is a gift, and the plates may have to be returned to the state and new ones are issued (for money). The original owner may need to report the sale. There is a good chance that the executor of the estate will have to sign an affadavit (with notary) and a supply current & official letter of testamentary and death certificate, and also the state will not just say up front (online) what is required so yo may have to call them. Assuming the daughter is the executor, there is a fair amount of hassle for her but by following the specific steps for your state and calling the DMV, you could reduce the hassle.